# Как поместить элементы header в одну линию?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Prompt:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>52</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <ul class="navigator">
      <li class="nav-item1"><a href="#" class="navv">Payments</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item1"><a href="#" class="navv">Travel</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item1"><a href="#" class="navv">Loyalty</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item1"><a href="#" class="navv">Tickets</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item1"><a href="#" class="navv">Security</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="year">
      2020-2023
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body {
  background-color: #0D0D0D;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: "Prompt", sans-serif;
}
.navv {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.navigator {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 35px
}
.nav-item1 {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.year {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Надо чтобы меню навигации было в одну линию с годом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Например сделать `header` флексом и применить нужное выравнивание:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #0D0D0D;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: "Prompt", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.navv {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.navigator {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.nav-item1 {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.year {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
/* Header делаем флексом и применяем выравнивание */
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 35px; /* Отступ сверху перенесен сюда */
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="navigator">
    <li class="nav-item1"><a href="#" class="navv">Payments</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item1"><a href="#" class="navv">Travel</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item1"><a href="#" class="navv">Loyalty</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item1"><a href="#" class="navv">Tickets</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item1"><a href="#" class="navv">Security</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="year">2020-2023</div>
</header>
```